# how to using Rsync without SSH and rsh

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am trying to setup Lsync + Rsync for 2 Server target files synchronization, I already run `Rsync --daemon` at Server01, is there any way we can use Rsync to access Server01 without SSH and rsh? because I think `Rsync --daemon` already opened port 873 for accepting TCP connection, but i failed if I turn-off sshd.

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really connect to port 873 when sshd is running on Server1? It sounds weird that you would loose connection when dropping the sshd daemon. My guess is that when sshd is running you use that connection rather than the port 873.

Anyway i would suggest checking your firewall setup. I would do it by placing netcat to listen on server 1 and then try to netcat to that from server 2:

```
Server1: nc -l -p 873
Server2: nc server1.com -p 873
```

I am no expert on the issue, but briefly looking at the man page [1] it should be doable, at least with options 'auth_users': "The default is for all users to be able to connect without a password" : That is, you might need some configuration parameters toggled.

[1] http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf

Comment: Thanks for response. I opened 873 TCP and UDP in iptables (BTW: my platform is CentOS 6.4). anyway, i will try to use wireshark to capture trace again.    so with port 873 access, which Linux user or permission is used during access Rsync daemon server filesystem for synchornization?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, the permissions that the remote machine 'seems to have' are probably the same as the daemon permissions, but the daemon itself restricts access to files, see the configuration file example:
    uid = nobody
    gid = nobody
    use chroot = yes
    max connections = 4
    syslog facility = local5
    pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
    [ftp]
        path = /var/ftp/./pub
        comment = whole ftp area (approx 6.1 GB)

Comment: hi,     i have succeed to use Rsync over TCP port 873, without SSH/rsh now. the key is using <host>::<share-module> as the SRC/DES, not <user>@<host>:<dir>.   a further question, could we use Rsync over TLS?

Comment: about the uid/gid configuration on Rsync daemon side, i am not clear till now, digging...

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the "Rsync without SSH" part, since I was looking for it as a way to rsync without typing password, you can use `sshpass` to connect Rsync, it bypasses the need to interact with shell by providing the password for you (command line or script).

It may not be as secure as providing auth keys to servers, though.